# Is there a better way for to do this animation in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, css-animations, react-props

Hi I am currently building a ecom website that uses a few animations. The problem I have is that the current solution that have came up with doesn't seem right for the way I think react is used. This is my first project with react and might be a little above my level but I do believe I can finish it. The animation : when I scroll down I want the image to shrink but I dont want the header to move, and when scrolling up I want the image to grow. The problem : The code in the section below works but I feel that behind the scenes its might make my app slower. The other problem is that I used document.body.style.overflow = "hidden", I feel that when the header is not shown by maybe going to another section of the app that it would stop the app from being able to scroll. I am looking for help with a solution that doesn't have these problems I honestly don't know of another way to do this. Any solutions, critism, and learning material to improve the way I solve a problem will be greatly appreciated.

```
 const Header = () => {
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const [direction, setDirection] = useState('down');

  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const header = useRef(null);

  const callbackFunction = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries
    setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting)
  }

  const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 1.0
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, options)
    if (header.current) observer.observe(header.current)

    return () => {
      if(header.current) observer.unobserve(header.current)
    }
  }, [header, options])


  const handleDirection = (event) => {

   if (isVisible) {
    const value = event.deltaY;

    if (value > 0 && count <= 6) {
      setCount((count) => count + 1);
      setDirection((direction) => direction = 'down');

    } else if (value < 0 && count >= 1) {
      setCount((count) => count - 1);
      setDirection((direction) => direction = 'up');
    }
   } 
  }

  if (isVisible && count < 6) {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  } else if (isVisible && count === 7) {
    document.body.style.overflow = ''
  }

  console.log(count);
```

return (

```
  <div className="img-container" 
  style={{ animation: `${direction}Scale${count} 0.2s ease forwards`}}>
    <img src={require('../img/header-img (3).jpg')} alt="Skater" />
  </div>
  <OverlayHero />

  <div className="background-text-container">
    <span className="scrolling-texts">* WE ALWAYS CHECK THE QUALITY *<span className="hollow-texts"> WE ALWAYS CHECK THE QUALITY * </span>* ART ON MAPLE MATERPIECES *</span>
    <span className="scrolling-texts"><span className="hollow-texts"> RECYCLED MATERIAL * </span>* RECYCLED MATERIALS *<span className="hollow-texts"> RECYCLED MATERIAL * </span></span>
    <span className="scrolling-texts">* ART ON MAPLE MATERPIECES *
```

ART ON MAPLE MASTERPIECES * * ART ON MAPLE MATERPIECES *


)

in my css I have about 14 keyframe animations that is changed to the right one based on the count.
ex =

```
@keyframes upScale1 {
    from {
        width: 90vw;
        height: 98vh;  
    }
    to {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;  
    }
}
```